# How would I make python press Enter

Tags: python, enter

So say Im trying to paste a text into skype. I already know how to paste it I just need to know how to make it press enter.

Comment: How are you pasting the text? with what?

Comment: What did you try so far?where is it??,,you should include and what you have tried and tel us what bugs you,this is like tell the community to write everything for you from the scratch of which is against Stackoverflow rules!

Comment: How did you paste some text in Skype? From using a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, win32com will help you.

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)
```

I hope this helped!